# sed ungreedy matching

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I believe sed is unable to do ungreedy matching. Is there a way to have sed not match a new line character?

I am using the sed as follows, but the latter (.*) is matching everything as intended, but also matching an unwanted new line.

```
sed -i -s -r 's|^([A-Za-z0-9*()])(.*)|INSERT INTO `` (`f1`, `f2`, `f3`, `f4`, `f5`) VALUES (NULL, "", "", "\1\2", "" )|' /path/to/files/*
```

The output I get is

```
INSERT INTO `` (`f1`, `f2`, `f3`, `f4`, `f5`) VALUES (NULL, "", "", "Some text
", "" )
```

Comment: There are no newlines in the buffer to match with `.*`.  `sed` reads the input line by line and will never retain the actual newline-delimiter in the edit buffer. The only newlines there are newlines that you insert yourself, with commands like `N` or by substituting in a literal newline, etc. Can you give an example of the input to your command that would replicate this behaviour?

Comment: Also mention whether you are creating the input as DOS text files (with CRLF line endings) on a Windows machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If one of my input files look like

```
Abba
Ebbo
Obbe
```

... then your command can be expected to modify this into

```sql
INSERT INTO `` (`f1`, `f2`, `f3`, `f4`, `f5`) VALUES (NULL, "", "", "Abba", "" )
INSERT INTO `` (`f1`, `f2`, `f3`, `f4`, `f5`) VALUES (NULL, "", "", "Ebbo", "" )
INSERT INTO `` (`f1`, `f2`, `f3`, `f4`, `f5`) VALUES (NULL, "", "", "Obbe", "" )
```

However, if your input file is a DOS text file with CRLF line endings, the trailing carriage return character will cause the result to be instead presented as

```
", "" )INTO `` (`f1`, `f2`, `f3`, `f4`, `f5`) VALUES (NULL, "", "", "Abba
", "" )INTO `` (`f1`, `f2`, `f3`, `f4`, `f5`) VALUES (NULL, "", "", "Ebbo
", "" )INTO `` (`f1`, `f2`, `f3`, `f4`, `f5`) VALUES (NULL, "", "", "Obbe
```

... if the file is processed on a Unix system.

This is due to the carriage return character moving the cursor back to the start of the line when interpreted by the terminal.

The *actual* data, in this case, is (with `\r` symbolising the carriage return characters)

```
INSERT INTO `` (`f1`, `f2`, `f3`, `f4`, `f5`) VALUES (NULL, "", "", "Abba\r", "" )
INSERT INTO `` (`f1`, `f2`, `f3`, `f4`, `f5`) VALUES (NULL, "", "", "Ebbo\r", "" )
INSERT INTO `` (`f1`, `f2`, `f3`, `f4`, `f5`) VALUES (NULL, "", "", "Obbe\r", "" )
```

To fix this, convert your input files from DOS text files to Unix text files.  This could be done in bulk with a tool such as `dos2unix`, or you may do it as part of your `sed` command:

```bash
sed -i \
    -e 's/[[:space:]]$//' \
    -e 's/^[[:alnum:]*()].*/INSERT INTO `` (`f1`, `f2`, `f3`, `f4`, `f5`) VALUES (NULL, "", "", "&", "" )/' files
```

The first expression removes a single space-like character from the end of each line (the carriage return character is one of these), and the second expression performs your substitution.

Note that `-s` and `-r` are not needed because you don't rely on line numbers, and you don't need extended regular expression support.

Comment: Oh I believe the issue is with DOS files as I copied them from a windows system, it's probably easier and simpler to run dos2unix over them. I thought I read something in the man page about -s being about treating file separately, also didn't realise I didn't need extended regular expression support.

Comment: @AeroMaxx Yes, `-s` would treat each file separately, but that only matters if your `sed` commands use line number addressing, which you don't. You don't need extended regular expressions because you only used that to be able to type `(...)` instead of `\(...\)`, while in fact we don't need to capture anything. Instead we use `&` to insert _everything that was matched_ in the replacement text.

Comment: How did you know about the `&` I didn't know that you could do that instead of \1 \2 as I was originally trying to use. On another note I tested what you put as is with the DOS and it worked perfectly.

Comment: @AeroMaxx To be honest, I don't remember how I know about using `&` to insert the matching text. I've been using `sed` for 30 years, so I guess I've read the manual a few times... that might be it :-)

Comment: I don't suppose you would know how to do multi line matching with sed? For example if I had 3 lines and I wanted to capture the text between lines 1 and 3, and add it to line 1, removing line 2 in the process.

Comment: @AeroMaxx Possibly, if I could look at the data. It would be best if you asked a separate question about that (this allows for input from others too). Note that depending on what the data is, `sed` might or might not be the best tool for the job. If it's a structured document format (JSON, YAML, XML, etc.), then `sed` is less likely to be the best tool.